# How do I display only orders where all items are complete?

Tags: sql-server

I am new to programming so please be kind.
I do not even know where to start with this problem...

I am trying to write a sql view to display only orders that are complete.
I have a table that looks something like this

[image: sample table]

The result should display orders 1 and 3 since they have all completed items. Order 2 should not be displayed since one of the items is still "F" I only want to show the order once regardless of how many items.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks
software - SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 0):

you can use `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` for the conditions that you wanted

```
SELECT Order_nbr
FROM   yourtable
GROUP BY Order_nbr
HAVING MIN (completed) = 'P'
```

for completed order, the `completed` column will all be 'P', so `MIN(completed)` will be 'P'

for non-completed order, the `completed` column will contain at least a `F`, so `MIN(completed)` will gives you `F`